# I have created a trigger to delete from 2 tables. How do I execute the trigger?

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables.  1 is golf courses, the other is each hole on those courses.  So table `golf_courses` has 5 records (5 golf courses).  Table `golf_holes` has 18 records for each of the 5 courses (90 records).  I have created a trigger that I believe will delete the 18 holes when I delete the course.  But I dont know how to run it.

Here is my trigger:

```
Delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER remove_course
AFTER DELETE ON golf_courses
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM golf_holes
      WHERE golf_holes.golf_id = old.golf_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

How do I run/call this trigger?

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize the lines wrapped around ...

Comment: Delimiter $$ CREATE TRIGGER remove_course AFTER DELETE ON golf_courses FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DELETE FROM golf_holes WHERE golf_holes.golf_id = old.golf_id; END $$ DELIMITER ;

Comment: The word `trigger` should associate you with triggering *because* of something, ergo it hints at something happening. It means you don't execute it. You execute programs (hence the word stored procedure, as you invoke it manually). Triggers get **triggered**. You even wrote its body, which states `AFTER DELETE` - it means it gets **triggered** after delete happens. Events get executed when time component is satisfied etc. I don't know what confused you, but since you knew you needed the trigger and how to create it.. quite odd you don't know how or why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are automatic, it should run when you perform the specified action on the specified table; in this case, when you DELETE from `golf_courses`.

Comment: ok, then its not working.  I type in:  DELETE FROM golf_courses WHERE golf_id = 1;   It deletes the golf course from the first table, but not the 18 holes from the 2nd table

Comment: Is there an foreign key constraint on golf_holes.golf_id referencing golf_courses.golf_id? If so, the constraint may have an `ON DELETE SET NULL` clause, that changes those 1's to nulls before the trigger is executed; that would be the reason Alfabravo's answer suggested using a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger instead.

Answer (score 0):

It will be called automatically on each delete operation over rows on `golf_courses`. I'd set it to execute `before delete` because there could be constraints on effect keeping you from deleting rows in that table having child tables (`golf_holes`) with related rows